# Warning: ReactNative.createElement is deprecated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating simple two bars item app using React Native.
I got such warning after building

```
Warning: ReactNative.createElement is deprecated. Use React.createElement from the "react" package instead.
```

And as a result, I don't see any tab icons.

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Featured = require('./Featured');
var Search = require('./Search');

var {
    AppRegistry,
    TabBarIOS,
    Component
   } = React;


class BookSearch extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedTab: 'featured'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
                <TabBarIOS.Item
                    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'featured'}
                    icon={{uri:'featured'}}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedTab: 'featured'
                        });
                    }}>
                    <Featured/>
                </TabBarIOS.Item>
                <TabBarIOS.Item
                    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'search'}
                    icon={{uri:'search'}}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            selectedTab: 'search'
                        });
                    }}>
                    <Search/>
                </TabBarIOS.Item>
            </TabBarIOS>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('BookSearch', () => BookSearch);
```

I surfed here and find, that in newest version I should use something like that:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    AppRegistry,
    TabBarIOS,
    Component
} from 'react-native';
```

But, when I rewrite my code in that way I got an error:

```
 Complex binding patterns require an initialization value (18:4)
```

How can I fix it.

Comment: *"How can I fix it."* Most likely depends on the errors. When I get an unfamiliar error, I google for it first.

Comment: What errors are you getting ? Taking a wild shot. component needs to be imported from react.  import React, {
  Component,
} from 'react';

Comment: @agent_hunt edited Q with an error description

Comment: Sorry. A similar example works fine. Must be something else other than this code. Try removing the Search and Feature require components.